# Marshal.GetActiveObject COM run time exception HRESULT 0x800401E3

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get a hold of the excel application that is open. I'm using the `Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")` method to do this. I open the excel workbook manually and then try and get a hold of it. There is only one instance of excel open so I'm not sure why I'm getting a `COMException` saying `Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))`

My code is as follows

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oExcelApp=null;
        oExcelApp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") as Excel.Application;
```

Comment: Im not getting the same error although my code is marginally different

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/238610/getobject-or-getactiveobject-cannot-find-a-running-office-application

Comment: @HansPassant I would like to think it should be registered on the ROT as when I open Excel I click on "Blank workbook" and then enter some data into the cells. Would I be correct in saying this?

Comment: @BugFinder could you please show me your code and are you opening Excel manually or through interop?

Answer (score 0):

Craig

I use:

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oExcelApp = null;
    try
    {
       oExcelapp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
    }
    catch {} // can do intelligent stuff here    
    if (oExcelApp == null)
    { Console.WriteLine("Excel not found"); }
    else
    {Console.WriteLine(oExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.FullName);}
```

Comment: I get the same error as I was getting? Is it because I don't launch excel using interop. I even ran through the processes and you can see Excel is running

Comment: odd - this never fails to work for me, i get an error if theres no excel running without the try loop- and if you arent running as the user some of this may fail.... because I think it only looks at your own processes, and that for example is the entire code of an app... so it works with manual opening

Comment: Yea I don't understand could I be missing something that happens beforehand? It just goes into the if statement saying oExcelApp=null

Comment: But without the try if it doesnt find one.. it errors.